# How to get all the parent elements of XML validation error?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xsd, simplexml

```
    <information>
      <person>
        <address>      
          <region>
            <city>
              <ZIP>1701</ZIP>
            </city>
          </region>
        </address>
      </person>
      <company>
        <address>      
          <region>
            <city>
              <ZIP>This is not a ZIP Code</ZIP>
            </city>
          </region>
        </address>
      </company>
    </information>
```

Above is an example XML element format. And if I validate it to the XSD, this will return an error : "ZIP element is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:integer' "

to catch the error, I use libxml_get_errors(). but this  cannot return the parent elements where the error occurred. It would be difficult to know if the ZIP error occurred inside  OR .

Do you guys know another XML error library to return element error hierarchically? or any other way to achieve something like this? :

" < information >< company >< address >< region >< city > : ZIP is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:integer' "

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, [`libxml_get_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.libxmlerror.php) returns the exact line on which the error occurs.

Comment: Hi @RobbyCornelissen thank you for the reply :) I am planning to have something like: information > company > contact > phone element 'this is not a phone number' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:integer' ?
I wanted to show the error to the user, so if I can achieve on what specific element hierarchy the error occurred, I can deliver it to the user as an error message. And it will be easier for them to know on what group of data the phone has an error